# Compare and test 00:00:00 time occurrence for scheduler

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

For a scheduler - Start Time, End Time and NextOccurance Minutes or Hours are given.
For that I have prepared logic as below

```
SET @StartTime = 17:00:00 
SET @TEMP_TIME = StartTime --initially
SET @ENDTIME = 23:59:59
SET @RepeatTimeUnit = 1 --assume unit is hour 
SET @RepeatTimeCount = 1 --to consider one hour
```

after execution of below loop, start time will be updated. But when I am running it between 11PM  and 12 AM it will take 00:00:00 as @NEXT_TIME in this case. SO, condition

```
if(@NEXT_TIME>@CUR_TIME)
```

is always false and thus loop goes in infinite execution mode. But except this duration the same logic works well.

How to handle this situation?
Thanks for suggestion.

```
IF(@StartTime<@CUR_TIME  AND  @ENDTIME>@CUR_TIME)
WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN
SET @NEXT_TIME=(SELECT CASE @RepeatTimeUnit WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(HH,@RepeatTimeCount,@TEMP_TIME) WHEN 2 THEN DATEADD(MI,@RepeatTimeCount,@TEMP_TIME) END)
SET @TEMP_TIME = @NEXT_TIME
IF(@NEXT_TIME>@CUR_TIME) BREAK
else CONTINUE
END
SET @StartTime=@NEXT_TIME
```

Comment: Maybe keeping the last execution time would help you on that.

Comment: @EvertonAgner, you are right. I modified it and kept record of previous calculation in separate variable. Though will test it finally tomorrow between 11PM & 12AM.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily resolve this (assuming you are using `TIME` datatype) with:

```
if(@NEXT_TIME>@CUR_TIME 
    OR (DATEPART(hh, @NEXT_TIME) = 0 
        AND DATEPART(hh, @CUR_TIME) = 11))
```

If you're using strings for this, you can compare the leftmost 2 characters fairly easily as well.